# Error javax.naming.NamingException

Tags: java, netbeans, jakarta-ee, jndi

i new using j2ee, when i running this project using netbean 6.9 . I got this problem

```
javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'java:comp/env' in SerialContext  [Root exception is javax.naming.NamingException: Invocation exception: Got null ComponentInvocation ]
        at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:442)
        at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:392)
        at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:392)
        at com.askad.ap.util.ListReader.readPath(ListReader.java:34)
        at com.askad.ap.util.ListReader.<init>(ListReader.java:29)
        at com.askad.ap.facade.UserTransactionFacade.<init>(UserTransactionFacade.java:44)
        at com.askad.ap.facade.__EJB31_Generated__UserTransactionFacade__Intf____Bean__.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:355)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:308)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.instantiateOptionalEJBLocalBusinessObjectImpl(BaseContainer.java:3801)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.StatelessSessionContainer.initializeHome(StatelessSessionContainer.java:248)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.ContainerFactoryImpl.createContainer(ContainerFactoryImpl.java:161)
        at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbApplication.loadContainers(EjbApplication.java:207)
        at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbDeployer.load(EjbDeployer.java:197)
        at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbDeployer.load(EjbDeployer.java:63)
        at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.load(ModuleInfo.java:175)
        at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.load(ApplicationInfo.java:216)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:338)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:183)
        at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:272)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$1.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:305)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:320)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1176)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$900(CommandRunnerImpl.java:83)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1235)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1224)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:365)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.service(AdminAdapter.java:204)
        at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.GrizzlyAdapter.service(GrizzlyAdapter.java:166)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.HK2Dispatcher.dispath(HK2Dispatcher.java:100)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:245)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:791)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:693)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:954)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:170)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:135)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:102)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:88)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:76)
        at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:53)
        at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:57)
        at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:69)
        at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:330)
        at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:309)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: javax.naming.NamingException: Invocation exception: Got null ComponentInvocation 
        at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.getComponentId(GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.java:773)
        at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.lookup(GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.java:655)
        at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.JavaURLContext.lookup(JavaURLContext.java:156)
        at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:428)
        ... 48 more
```

when i click

```
com.askad.ap.util.ListReader.readPath(ListReader.java:34)
```

NetBean give highlight to this line

```
Context env = (Context) new InitialContext().lookup("java:comp/env");
```

Anyone know how to resolve this problem?And what cause this problem? Thx b4

Comment: *Why* are you looking up that context? Are you trying to list it perhaps? It normally doesn't support list().

Answer (score 1):

From the stack trace, it looks like you're using Glassfish as your container. In the context.xml you should have one or more resources defined. Let's say you have one called jdbc/msql. Then you would refer to it using java:comp/env/jdbc/msql. It looks like you're referring to some null resource in that questionable line of code. Hth.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen that exception when trying to access the java:comp/env namespace from a thread on which it was not accessible. I solved it by using a global identifier (e.g., just "jdbc/msql" instead of "java:comp/env/jdbc/msql").

You could also probably get the object once where you can (e.g., via @Resource injection) and then reference it from any thread.

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting this error in glassfish, try to look for the file `sun-web.xml`.
It may happen if this file is missing.